# override OnPaint for a Windows.Forms.Control Flickering?

Tags: .net, winforms, graphics, controls, onpaint

I create a new Control and overided the OnPaint event:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        _ammo = PitControl.Ammo;
        var AmmoSize = g.MeasureString(_ammo.ToString(), Properties.Settings.Default.AmmoFont).ToSize();
        g.DrawString(_ammo.ToString(), Properties.Settings.Default.AmmoFont, Brushes.WhiteSmoke, Ammo.Location.X - 1, Ammo.Location.Y + Ammo.Height / 2 - AmmoSize.Height / 2 + 1);
        Rectangle DrawAmmo = new Rectangle(this.Width - Ammo.Height - _margin, Ammo.Location.Y, Ammo.Height, Ammo.Height);
        for (int i = _ammo; i > 0; i--)
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                g.DrawLine(_ammoPen, Ammo.Location.X + Ammo.Width - i - 1, Ammo.Location.Y + 3, Ammo.Location.X + Ammo.Width - i - 1, Ammo.Location.Y + Ammo.Height - 3);
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Orange, Ammo);
        g.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.ammunition, DrawAmmo.Location.X, DrawAmmo.Location.Y, DrawAmmo.Height, DrawAmmo.Height);
    }
```

[image]

The problem is when i'm changing the Ammo then all the control flicks.

It doesn't look good.

Anyway to make the lines that i draw on this line:

```
g.DrawLine(_ammoPen, Ammo.Location.X + Ammo.Width - i - 1, Ammo.Location.Y + 3, Ammo.Location.X + Ammo.Width - i - 1, Ammo.Location.Y + Ammo.Height - 3);
```

Just disapeare when ammo is changing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick thing you can check.

For the form, not the control, set the `DoubleBuffered` property to `true`.

That should remove the flickering, but Windows.Forms is not very good to use for games in general, so don't expect and great frame rates.

Comment: You're sure you set it on the actual Form, and not some component? Components have a DoubleBuffered property as well. Long time since I worked with WinForms now, but I remember having the exact same problem, and DoubleBuffered came to the rescue (even if it affected the drawing performance quite a bit)

Comment: Yes i set it on the form and it didn't work, but now i also set it to on the component and it works ! thx :)

Comment: Great to hear it worked out in the end :) Good luck with your game.